# Check folder exists in Access Continous Forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm modifying an existing Access 2003 application, through some machines have Access 2010 instead of 2003.

I have a continuous form which includes an unbound textbox with the word "folder". The textbox has an onClick event to open a folder which relates to the current record.

For each row, I want to indicate to the user whether a folder exists for that row. The way I'd prefer to do this is that if there is no folder for a row, the 'folder' textbox is blank, like this:

```
Quote Ref   Customer   Cust.Ref

14-243    | Smiths    |CR342   | Folder |
14-269    | Cox & Son |0002634 |        |
14-314    | RedBox    |436R    | Folder |
14-314    | JTG PRs   |63462   |        |
```

The folder name is made up of the first 3 fields:
"**S:/path/14-243 Smiths CR342/**"

I originally tried putting some code on the *form_current* event to change the visiblity of the text box, but this set all rows the same.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  If Len(Dir("S:/path/" & [quote_no] & " " & [customer] & " " & [cust_ref], vbDirectory) = 0) Then
     Me.txtFolder.Visible = False
  Else
     Me.txtFolder.Visible = True
  End If
End Sub
```

So I tried putting this code into the control source

```
=iif(Len(Dir("S:/path/" & [quote_no] & " " & [customer] & " " & [cust_ref],vbDirectory)) =0,"","Folder")
```

But Access assumes vbDirectory is a control and puts square brackets around it, which breaks the syntax. I assume therefore that dir() cannot be used on a control source.

Can you suggest how can I achieve my aims?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make wrapper for the `FileSystemObjec`'s `FolderExists` function like this

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject   'So a new object is not created on every call to FolderExists

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
End Sub

Function FolderExists(folderPath As String) As Boolean
    FolderExists = fso.FolderExists(folderPath)
End Function
```

To use the `FileSystemObject` you'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Then in the control source of your textbox have a function call like this

```
=FolderExists("S:/path/" & [quote_no] & " " & [customer] & " " & [cust_ref])
```

Or even

```
=IIF(FolderExists("S:/path/" & [quote_no] & " " & [customer] & " " & [cust_ref]),"Click","")
```

Then in the click event for your textbox check if it is clickable

```
Private Sub Text1_Click()
    If Text1.Text = "Click" Then
        Debug.Print "Do some work"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Do nothing"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job! It took me a while to get it to work – I eventually discovered that I needed to add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference. Now working fine (though it is quite slow).

Comment: Ah yes! I'm sorry I didn't mention that. Well done for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Debug window in VBA and type `? vbDirectory`. This will return you the value of the constant (16, in fact).
Replace the constant by its value in the control source expression.
Not sure the Dir function exists outside VBA. If not use a wrapper (which could be a better idea anyway).

I suspect that using such a slow function on a continuous form will make it very slow.
If that suits your Use Case, I would recommend putting the control in the header or the footer of the form. This way, only the current record is calculated (valid also if using the wrapper version).

Comment: Gives `#Name` error. Good suggestion but I think Dir being recognized is the bottleneck then